# Why does a component not render correctly in Reagent?

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

When perusing [this post](https://holmsand.github.io/reagent/) on Reagent with Clojurescript I experimented with different ways to implement the `timer-component` component. My first attempt, however, did not work:

```
(defn timer-component []
  (fn []
    (let [seconds-elapsed (r/atom 0)]
      (js/setTimeout #(swap! seconds-elapsed inc) 1000)
      [:p (str "Expired time: " @seconds-elapsed)])))
```

As a debug log statement reveals the timer is still called regularly and the `seconds-elapsed` variable is still updated correctly. The display, however, is not updated and the component always shows "Expired time: 0".

Compared to the code example in the blog post my component interchanges the `fn` and the `let` declarations and this modification seems to prevent proper display, but not proper updates of the component. My expectation was that either the component is both updated and displayed properly or neither updates nor displays.

My question is why does this happen? Is this a bug in Reagent or some misuse of the API on my part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always seeing the same value, because the inner anonymous function is being called for every (re-)render. Thus, `seconds-elapsed` is being bound again and again to a new atom with value 0. This is not a bug, but how Reagent is supposed to work.

Your component is "Form-2" and should declare its local state in the outer function `timer-component`, which is called only once per component. [Re-frame documentation explains different forms of Reagent components](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/wiki/Creating-Reagent-Components#form-2--a-function-returning-a-function) nicely.

Re-frame docs add comments to the example in the Reagent tutorial, which may help to clarify:

```
(defn timer-component []
  (let [seconds-elapsed (reagent/atom 0)]     ;; setup, and local state
    (fn []        ;; inner, render function is returned
      (js/setTimeout #(swap! seconds-elapsed inc) 1000)
      [:div "Seconds Elapsed: " @seconds-elapsed])))
```